Noun ending question
In the seventh Gereon Rath novel, the character Liang Kuen-Yao says "Für die Chinesen bin ich Deutscher, für die Deutschen Chinese." Why the different endings for the  nouns Deutscher and Chinese?

Because Deutscher is a nominalized adjective, whereas Chinese is a proper noun (weak declension).
You might know that German adjectives can be used without an accompanying noun, and nominalized adjectives are a form where the result is then treated as a noun. There is no difference to a normal noun except in its declination. Another example you might encounter is "Verwandter".
So "Ein Deutscher", "Der Deutsche" is like "Ein deutscher Mann", "Der deutsche Mann". Whereas "Chinese", like "Mensch", is a weak declension noun. It has "Chinesen" in all forms but nominative singular.
They are also different in how they form feminine forms: Die Deutsche und die Chinesin.
You could do the same as in Deutschen and call Chinesen Chinesische, but this would not be very idiomatic.

In general, the answer is that there isn't a single pattern that all nouns denoting nationals of a country follow in German.
In this particular case, we see two different patterns:

Chinese is a nount hat happens to end in -se, which is an ending shared with various other nationalities - Franzose, Kongolese, Taiwanese.
Deutscher, in contrast, is actually a "substantiviertes Adjektiv", an adjectiv transformed into a noun. Therefore, its ending is a result of inflecting the adjective deutsch. The result is [ein] Deutscher (though note that this noun, being based on an adjective, changes depending on the article - hence, with a definite article, it becomes [der] Deutsche).

The -er ending of Deutscher should not be confused with the -er ending of some other nationalities, where the nouns are not derived from an adjective - e.g. Amerikaner or Indonesier.

"The -er ending of Deutscher should not be confused with the -er ending of some other nationalities, where the nouns are not derived from an adjective - e.g. Amerikaner or Indonesier." Why not? What is the difference?

@Steve: The difference is that e.g. Amerikaner is not a noun derived from an adjective. The adjective would be amerikanisch, so the derived noun would be Amerikanischer, where the outlined inflection rules (ein Amerikanischer vs. der Amerikanische) apply again (but it's unidiomatic). In contrast, both ein Amerikaner and der Amerikaner have the -er ending.

A similar derivation to Amerika => Amerikaner (or Pfalz => Pfälzer or Bayern => Bayer), but for Deutschland, would be Deutschländer, but beware of that, we only use that for sausages. :-)
